# Asp.Net Core-Validation and submit form with Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a form in the modal popup?

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">
<div class="form-area" id="Register-Form" hidden>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="user_Password" class="input-field" maxlength="6" id="Register-NewPassword">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="input-field" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off" id="Register-ActiveCode"> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
    <button  type="submit" onclick="return Validate_Register()" class="mybtn">Save </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Validation :

```
 function Validate_Register() { 
    $.post("/Account/CheckActiveCode", {
        Mobile: Login_Mobile, ActiveCode: Register_Active_Value
    }, function (data) {
        if (data == 1) {
            $.alert({
                title: 'Error',
                content: 'Active Code is Not True',
                rtl: true,
                closeIcon: true,
                type: 'red',
                typeAnimated: true,
                buttons: {
                    confirm: {
                        text: 'Ok',
                        btnClass: 'btn-red',
                    }
                },
            });
            return false;
        }       
            
    });

    return true;
}
```

Controller :

```
public JsonResult CheckActiveCode(string Mobile , string ActiveCode)
    {            
        if (!_user.UserIsActivate(Mobile, ActiveCode))
        {
            return Json(1);
        }
        return Json(0);
    }
```

Controller Form for Submit:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Register(string mobile_User, string user_Password)
    {
        _user.RegisterUpdateUser(mobile_User, user_Password);
        
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

I want the form to be submitted if the validation (data==0)
If (data==1), the form will not be submitted and an error will be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `<input type="button"/>` to replace `<button></button>`,and if `data !=1`,submit form.

html code:

```
<form id="myForm" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">
<div class="form-area" id="Register-Form" hidden>
     <div class="form-group">
            <input name="mobile_User" class="input-field" maxlength="6" id="mobile_User">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="user_Password" class="input-field" maxlength="6" id="Register-NewPassword">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="input-field" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off" id="Register-ActiveCode">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <input type="button" onclick="Validate_Register()" class="mybtn" value="Save" />
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

js:

```
function Validate_Register() {
                $.post("CheckActiveCode", {
                    Mobile: Login_Mobile, ActiveCode: Register_Active_Value
                }, function (data) {
                        if (data == 1) {
                            $.alert({
                                title: 'Error',
                                content: 'Active Code is Not True',
                                rtl: true,
                                closeIcon: true,
                                type: 'red',
                                typeAnimated: true,
                                buttons: {
                                    confirm: {
                                        text: 'Ok',
                                        btnClass: 'btn-red',
                                    }
                                },
                            });
                        } else {
                            $("#myForm").submit();
                        }
                    })

            }
```

Comment: My code also submits the form ,I want the form not to be submitted when (data == 1)  and to display the error,Unfortunately, after becoming 1, the form is submitted

Comment: Yes,use `<input type="button"/>`, it will not be submitted when data==1.

Comment: Do you use my html code,such as `<form id="myForm" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">` in my code. `$("#myForm").submit();` will submit form which id is `myForm`,so you must add  `id="myForm"` to your form as I shown in my answer.